# How to spy an imported module's property in Angular / Karma / Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

In my Angular project I use Karma/Jasmine to test and I get error on running a spied serive's function.

This is my code:

```js
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        DdataCoreModule.forRoot(environment),
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: ValidatorService,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('ValidatorService', ['get'])
        }
      ]
    });
  });
```

My code is this:

```js
  it('should get errors on invalid required fields', () => {
    model = new Country().init({id: 1, name: ''});

    model.validate();

    // ...expectations...
  });
```

The model's validation function has this code:

```js
validate(preparedData?: any): void {
  const validatorService: ValidatorServiceInterface = DdataCoreModule.InjectorInstance.get<ValidatorServiceInterface>(ValidatorService);

  // ...
}
```

And I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at Country.validate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/ddata-core/fesm2015/ddata-core.mjs:793:67)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/modules/webshop/models/country/country.model.spec.ts:144:11)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:371:1)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:134:1)
    at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:567:1)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:582:1)
    at <Jasmine>
```

I think the `InjectorInstance` is undefined.

What I miss in my `TestBed` or in the test itself?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
showing the problem.
You can use [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to create a MRE.

The good part about making a MRE is that you might end up finding the problem yourself ;)
 And in case you don't, people can use the MRE to check where the problem lies.

Comment: You can use [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mtxscj?file=src/app/app.component.ts) to setup tests in a stackblitz based project!